# After capturing photo camera is till in photo capturing mode

Tags: android, android-camera, memo

I have a application to capture photo which will display on ImageView (and do some more work internally).

Problem is here when I open camera and after capturing photo, save and discard option come, after clicking on save button it again go to the camera mode.

This problem not occur when I clean the memory of phone(Task Manager ->> Ram ->> Clear Memory).

I thing the problem is: Camera Intent not give result when there is not sufficient memory.
But when I open normal Camera then it capture the photo.

How I solve this problem.
One solution is here every time clean memory before launching my application.

But this is not a right way because when I introduce my application to general people then they do not do these thing.

Now what I need to do here?

Is there any way to clean the memory by my application?
How I know what the minimum or maximum memory is utilized by my application. So first my application check, is there, that much memory available or not. If available then proceed otherwise tell user to clean(or uninstall some application) some memory.

I am using following code in my application:

layout->

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/photo"
    />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity->>

```
public class TestCameraActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_camera);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test_camera, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: try android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE instead of android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: Error: android.media.action cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are not properly calling [CameraIntent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html), try below code, hope it works:

`CameraIntent`

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/"+filename;
System.out.println("thumbnail path~~~~~~"+filepath);
File file = new File(filepath);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

`onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap=GlobalMethods.decodeFile(_path);//function to decode.
        if (bitmap == null) {
            ivPhy.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } 
        else {
            ivPhy.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ivPhy.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }


}
```

`Manifest Permission`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is looking any way try below code which worked for me

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Directory");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
         File file = new File(root,"filename.jpeg" );
         outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

         Intent photoPickerIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
   startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,100);
```

OnActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   

    switch(requestCode)
     { 

     case 100:
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     { 

           if(data==null)
            {
               Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
         break;
     }
}
}
```

Comment: In  one of my application I am using approx save code as you mention above to store photo on SdCard. But that application have the same problem while there is not sufficient memory. I think problem is not in the code, problem is in available memory. If sufficient memory is there then it work fine if memory is not there it not work. So first I need to know what the minimum memory which is used by my application and that much memory available or not.

Answer (score 0):

To those who are still searching solution for this issue:

lack of permission is one of the major reasons behind this problem.
Please add this permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```